# When switch from one branch to another, is target branch supposed to inherit index and changed files?

Tags: git

In Git, I have an experimental branch (`EXP-12`). I have done some changes there, but I am not ready for commit yet. I need to make adjustments on master.

I go to master.

Two cases are possible:

1. If I included my changes into index while on `EXP-12`, they will appear in index on master branch as well.
2. If I didn't include my changes into index while on `EXP-12`, those files will appear as changes not staged for commit on master branch as well.

My problem is that I want everything on master and `EXP-12` to be separate. I want to do some "experimental" changes on `EXP-12` > go to master > do changes on master > stage everything for commit (`git add -A`) > commit > switch back to EXP-12 and continue experiments. Now if I do that my commit at the master branch will include all changes done on `EXP-12`.

What is the logic behind that? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A classic solution to this problem is to use `git stash` - when you're on `EXP-12` you can do:

```
git stash save --keep-index "Some work-in-progress on EXP-12"
```

... then change branch to master as usual, do some work, change back, and apply that most recent stash:

```
git checkout master

[... do some stuff ...]

git checkout EXP-12

git stash pop
```

However, I personally prefer to create a work-in-progress commit, and later either:

- Change it with `git commit --amend`
- Move the branch back to the previous commit, but leaving all your work as unstaged changes with: `git reset HEAD^`
- ... or use `git rebase -i <EARLIER-COMMIT>` to squash several work-in-progress commits together.

The advantage of creating an actual commit over using the stash is that you can apply a stash on any commit, not just the one you saved it at, whereas a normal commit moves forward that branch and is tied to the earlier commits.

Comment: Thank you very much!! The thing I still don't get is why would git implement the logic I described above. To me, every branch should be atomic and separate from others. Am I wrong?

Comment: I actually find git's behaviour very helpful, particular since I frequently start making changes and then realize that I'd prefer to commit them on a different (often new) branch.  (If checking out a branch would cause a change to a file you have local modifications to, git won't let you switch branches.)  I guess the idea is just that until you've actually committed some changes they can "float" about - committing is the act that records them in the history.

Comment: OK. That helps a lot! Appreciate your help!!